# How to create a custom Sticky navbar in footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi there I'm trying to make sticky CTA in my site that is located in the footer https://desertroserecovery.com/old-treatment-program/detox/

this is the sample site: https://fherehab.com/ I want to clone the sticky cta that is enable in mobile devices

I'm using Avada theme in wordpress

[image]

here's my css

```
.sticky-footer-mobile{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added below css code in the custom css of Avada theme.

```
.fusion-footer .fusion-footer-widget-area  .sticky-footer-mobile{
     position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky!important;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.sticky-footer-mobile{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Please fix like this. Remove above css code in the custom css and add below code.

```
.fusion-footer .fusion-footer-widget-area  .sticky-footer-mobile{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Jeffery, did you checked it is working